# find records with same key but different second column value

Tags: sql

My Input data is :

```
Id salary  
101 1000  
101 1000  
102 2500  
102 3000  
105 5000   
105 5000  
105 5000  
106 12  
106 142  
106 12
```

Output :

```
102 2500  
102 3000  
106 12  
106 142  
106 12
```

I mean based on the id , I want to find out which Id has different salary. If the salary is the same in all the records , I want to discard those records. Kindly help.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from   t   
where  id in(
            select   Id
            from     t
            group by Id
            having   max(salary) <> min(salary)
            )
```

| Id | salary |
| --- | --- |
| 102 | 2500 |
| 102 | 3000 |
| 106 | 12 |
| 106 | 142 |
| 106 | 12 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8G4tQA-b?hide=4)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> SELECT `Id`, `salary` FROM salary 
>   WHERE Id IN( SELECT Id FROm salary GROUP By Id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SALARY) > 1)
> ```
>
> | Id | salary |
> | --- | --- |
> | 102 | 2500 |
> | 102 | 3000 |
> | 106 | 12 |
> | 106 | 142 |
> | 106 | 12 |
>
> ---
>
> [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QtdDHy-N)